# how to add select with static selection on typeorm

Tags: javascript, select, typeorm

i have some problem with typeorm

i cannot select empty string or static string in typeorm anyone has solve the problem

thank very much

here some sample code

```
 q3.addSelect(` `, 'start_date');
```

it generate query

```
,   AS \"start_date\"
```

and it generate error near syntax AS 
any help very appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

done, i using 
 q3.addSelect(`''`, 'start_date');

double quote not working in sql